# IFRAME with overflow:hidden still shows scrollbars in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

I am trying to force an IFRAME to never show scrollbars, but setting CSS attribute `overflow:hidden !important` is not working. Chrome's developer tools shows the ***applied style*** to be `overflow:hidden`, but the ***computed style*** as `overflow:visible`. See exact markup and CSS in screenshots below:

[image: Applied Style in Chrome Developer Tools]

[image: Computed Style in Chrome Developer Tools]

This seems like a bug in Chrome (this repros in Chromium, BTW). But I am still looking for a solution or workaround.

**More information:**

- The only scrollbar visible in the UI is the vertical one.
- Adding attribute `scrolling="no"` makes no difference.
- Explicitly adding `overflow-x: hidden !important` and `overflow-y: hidden !important` does not work either.
- Inline style doesn't make a difference.
- I do not control the HTML inside the IFRAME. This content is responsive (it adapts to the IFRAME's size).
- Increasing the `IFRAME`s width by 5 pixels gets rid  of the **vertical** scroll bar, but it
  also makes its content reflow and change layout completely.
- Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87.

Comment: Did you try adding the lines to element.style in devtools?

Comment: @JannisJorre Yes. Inline style doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

The scrollbar being rendered isn't of the iframe tag, rather than the html tag inside the iframe. So that is where the `overflow: hidden;` declaration should be applied to. The iframe itself does indeed have a hidden overflow.

Answer (score 3):

For Webkit only, you can try adding:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: on chrome, when you cannot change the iframe content - only this worked (for me)